# GlusterFS & Mercurial don't like each other

Tags: mercurial

I did setup GlusterFS but when I mounted the directory on the client and did `hg clone myrepo myrepo` in that mounted directory, it's giving the following error:

```
requesting all changes
adding changesets
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: integrity check failed on 00changelog.i:6!
```

1. When I go to a none Glusterfs directory then clone, hg works fine.
2. I checked out the code to a different directory then moved it to the mounted GlusterFS directory and it works fine.

So it must be that either Mercurial or GlusterFS has a bug but don't know if there is an alternative. Else I will have to use rsync from non mounted directory. Any idea what's going on here?

**Versions**

```
GlusterFS 3.2.6
Mercurial 2.1.1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this bug: [Direct io-mode support and related changes in caching translators](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=GLUSTER-801), described in [Write-behind breaks Mercurial](http://gluster.org/pipermail/gluster-users/2011-June/007956.html). The bug will  be fixed in GlusterFS 3.4.0 (I don't know if is fixed in 3.3, anyway [try the beta](http://www.gluster.org/community/documentation/index.php/3.3beta)), according to the Bugzilla entry.

As a workaround, is suggested to disable write-behind: `gluster volume set conf performance.write-behind off`.